# Pick one random element from a vector for each row of a data.table

Tags: r, data.table, sample

I have a dataframe of names. And I have a vector of different food items. I want to pick one element from that vector randomly for each Name so that the data.table looks like below.

```
x<- c("apple","pepsi","rice","coke","banana","butter","bread")

library(data.table)

dt <- fread('

Name  NextItem
John   rice
Logan  butter
Sarah  bread
Vinny  rice
')
```

I want the sampling with replacement. I have tried

`dt[,NextItem:= sample(x,1)]` but it samples the same food item(vector element) for everyone, not different random elements like aforementioned example.

Comment: You don't want to just pick 1 value, you want to pick one for each row: `dt[,NextItem:= sample(x,length(Name))]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use group by option and then do `sample`

```
dt[, NextItem := sample(x, 1), by = Name]
```

Or you can also do this with `.N` instead of `by`

```
dt[, NextItem := sample(x, .N, replace = TRUE)]
```

Comment: Thank you for showing additional ways of doing it. How is .N operating here in the context of the sample function?

Comment: @gibbz00 `.N` gives the number of rows of the dataset, so `sample(x, .N)` will sample for 'x' with `size` as the number of rows..  As the default option is `replace=FALSE`, we can change it to `replace=TRUE`

Comment: The second way is far better for this case, in my opinion.

Comment: @Frank Thanks, actually, it was the first one I posted, then i changed it to `by = Name` after rereading his post.