# Select one random element from a vector after dynamically excluding certain values

Tags: r, vector, random, data.table

This is  my dataframe/data.table that shows what people has already eaten and my target field `NextItem` which is one next random item(uneaten) that they may eat

```
library(data.table)
dt <- read.table(text='
            Name   ItemEaten   NextItem
            John   rice        banana
            John   butter      banana
            Sarah  bread       apple
            Vinny  apple       coke   
            ',header=T)

setDT(dt)
```

And this vector `x` is my universe of food items:

```
x<- c("apple","pepsi","rice","coke","banana","butter","bread")
```

The `NextItem` field should only include food items from the `x` vector that is not already eaten by the given individual(not in `ItemEaten` Field). For example, John has already eaten `rice & butter`,thats why John should have one of the five remaining food items in the `NextItem` field. I have tried `dt[,NextItem:= sample(x- ItemEaten,1),by=Name]`

Comment: `x - ItemEaten` won't work for characters, as you've probably already discovered.  You need something like `setdiff(x, ItemEaten)` or `x[-match(ItemEaten, x)]` there.  I would probably go with `setdiff`

Comment: Or something like: `dt[, NextItem := sample(x[x!=ItemEaten], 1), by = 1:nrow(dt)]`

Comment: @nrussell That question was also asked by me. That question did not try to exclude anything from the x vector, it just randomized the full x vector for every name.

Comment: @ProcrastinatusMaximus you don't need by row operations as `sample` has `replace = FALSE` as default. Just `dt[, Test := sample(setdiff(x, ItemEaten), 1), by = Name]` should do IMO

Comment: @DavidArenburg true, however I was also showing an alternative for the comparison needs to by row (but inreality I missed the `by = Name` part and thought the operation needed to be by row ;-) )

Comment: Anyway, you could also negate with `%in%` or `is.element` for selecting the correct elements from `x`.

Comment: What do you mean with *"thats why John should have one of the five remaining food items in the `NextItem` field"*? Do both rows need to have the same element? Or can they differ?

Comment: Ideally I wanted both rows to have the same element. But they can differ as long as both rice and butter are not in the NextItem field in both cases.

Comment: Both the same: `dt[, NextItem := sample(setdiff(x, ItemEaten), 1), by = Name]` Not the same: `dt[, NextItem := sample(setdiff(x, ItemEaten), .N), by = Name]` Possibly the same: `dt[, NextItem := sample(setdiff(x, ItemEaten), .N, replace = TRUE), by = Name]`

Comment: @DirtySockSniffer why is .N showing different elements? I can see it is placed in the "size" argument of the sample function but cant intuitively see why.

Comment: @gibbz00 - akrun already answered that in your last question with [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39334812/pick-one-random-element-from-a-vector-for-each-row-of-a-data-table#comment66001392_39334828)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the contributions from all the above commenters, I was able to find a solution to my problem. The following code gets the job done perfectly.

```
dt[, NextItem := sample(setdiff(x, ItemEaten), 1), by = Name]
```